# Creating an interface for construction

Tags: dart

A few times now I've run into a use case where I need to define an interface for how classes construct themselves. One such example could be if I want to make an Interface Class that defines the interface by which objects can serialize and unserialize themselves (for input into a database, to be sent as JSON, etc). You might write something like this:

```dart
abstract class Serializable {
  String serialize();
  Serializable unserialize(String serializedString);
}
```

But now you have a problem, as `serialize()` is properly an instance method, and `unserialize()` should instead be a static method (which isn't inheritable or enforced by the Interface) or a constructor (which also isn't inheritable).

This leaves a state where classes that impliment the `Serializable` interface are required to define a `serialize()` method, but there is no way to require those classes to define a `static unserialize()` method or `Foo.fromSerializedString()` constructor.

If you make `unserialize()` an instance method, then unserializing an implementing class `Foo` would look like:

```dart
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo = foo.unserialize(serializedString);
```

which is rather cumbersome and ugly.

The only other option I can think of is to add a comment in the `Serializable` interface asking nicely that implementing classes define the appropriate static method or constructor, but this is obviously prone to error if a developer misses it and also hurts code completion.

So, is there a better way to do this? Is there some pattern by which you can have an interface which forces implementing classes to define a way to construct themselves, or something that gives that general effect?

Comment: What about splitting the serialization away from the Foo object into a FooSerializer? This FooSerializer would have both methods as instance methods.

Comment: In the last example, how does the code already know that the serializedString contains a Foo object? Typically when deserializing, the code doesn't know this in advance. So you would actually need a static method or a function which would start the deserialization and then delegate to the correct concrete implementation. This can be done quite elegantly using a Map<String,Function>. Also - in the Dart std lib it's usually called encode/decode, which I prefer over Java's serialization/deserialization.

Comment: I've added an answer with an example of what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use instance methods if you want the inheritance guarantees. You can do a bit nicer than manual instantiation though, by using reflection.

```dart
abstract class Serializable {

  static Serializable fromSerializedString(Type type, String serializedString) {
    ClassMirror cm = reflectClass(type);
    InstanceMirror im = cm.newInstance(const Symbol(''), []);
    var obj = im.reflectee;
    obj.unserialize(serializedString);
    return obj;
  }

  String serialize();
  void unserialize(String serializedString);
}
```

Now if someone implements `Serializable` they will be forced to provide an unserialize method:

```dart
class Foo implements Serializable {

  @override
  String serialize() {
    // TODO: implement serialize
  }

  @override
  void unserialize(String string) {
    // TODO: implement unserialize
  }
}
```

You can get an instance like so:

```dart
var foo = Serializable.fromSerializedString(Foo, 'someSerializedString');
```

This might be a bit prettier and natural than the manual method, but keep in mind that it uses reflection with all the problems that can entail.

If you decide to go with a static method and a warning comment instead, it might be helpful to also provide a custom [Transformer](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/assets-and-transformers.html) that scans through all classes implementing Serializable and warn the user or stops the build if any don't have a corresponding static unserialize method or constructor (similar to how Polymer does things). This obviously wouldn't provide the instant feedback the an editor could with instance methods, but would be more visible than a simple comment in the docs.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid reflection if I could help it. As you mentioned, there is a lot of baggage you take on once you start using them. The transformer idea sounds pretty interesting, though I can't say I've used them much before. Could you maybe give a more detailed example of how that might work (perhaps as a separate answer to the main question rather than a comment on this answer)?

Comment: I'm accepting this answer primarily for the Transformer suggestion. Mirrors could work, but there are a lot of reasons why you might want to avoid them. Transformers are the simplest solution that makes sure your code is alright without added a huge amount of overhead.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to come back to this and expand on the transformer part. I guess you figured it out anyway though.

Comment: Figured it out mostly anyway. If you wanted to submit a more detailed Transformers answer I'll change the accepted answer to that. Might help anyone finding this through Google in the future. PS: Hi people in from Google in the Future!

Answer (score 2):

I think this example is a more Dart-like way to implement the encoding and decoding. In practice I don't think "enforcing" the decode signature will actually help catch bugs, or improve code quality. If you need to make the decoder types pluggable then you can make the decoders map configurable.

```
const Map<String,Function> _decoders = const {
  'foo': Foo.decode,
  'bar': Bar.decode
};

Object decode(String s) {
  var obj = JSON.decode(s);
  var decoder = _decoders[obj['type']];
  return decoder(s);
}

abstract class Encodable {
  abstract String encode();
}

class Foo implements Encodable {
   encode() { .. }
   static Foo decode(String s) { .. }
}

class Bar implements Encodable {
   encode() { .. }
   static Foo decode(String s) { .. }
}

main() {
   var foo = decode('{"type": "foo", "i": 42}');
   var bar = decode('{"type": "bar", "k": 43}');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible pattern I've come up with is to create a Factory class that utilize instance methods in a slightly less awkward way.  Something like follows:

```dart
typedef Constructable ConstructorFunction();

abstract class Constructable {
  ConstructorFunction constructor;
}

abstract class Serializable {
  String serialize();
  Serializable unserialize(String serializedString);
}

abstract class SerializableModel implements Serializable, Constructable {
}

abstract class ModelFactory extends Model {    
  factory ModelFactory(ConstructorFunction constructor) {
    return constructor();
  }

  factory ModelFactory.fromSerializedString(ConstructorFunction constructor, String serializedString) {
    Serializable object = constructor();
    return object.unserialize(serializedString);
  }
}
```

and finally a concrete implementation:

```dart
class Foo extends SerializableModel {
  //required by Constructable interface
  ConstructorFunction constructor = () => new Foo();

  //required by Serializable interface
  String serialize() => "I'm a serialized string!";
  Foo unserialize(String serializedString) {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    //do unserialization work here to populate foo
    return foo;
  };
}
```

and now `Foo` (or anything that extends `SerializableModel` can be constructed with

```dart
Foo foo = new ModelFactory.fromSerializedString(Foo.constructor, serializedString);
```

The result of all this is that it enforces that every concrete class has a method which can create a new instance of itself from a serialized string, and there is also a common interface which allows that method to be called from a static context. It's still creating an extra object whose whole purpose is to switch from static to instance context, and then is thrown away, and there is a lot of other overhead as well, but at least all that ugliness is hidden from the user. Still, I'm not yet convinced that this is at all the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you define the unserialize function as named constructor like so:

```
abstract class Serializable<T> {
    String serialize();
    Serializable.unserialize(String serializedString);
}
```

This eliminates the need of static methods.
A possible implementation could look like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';
class JsonMap implements Serializable<JsonMap> {
    Map map = {};

    JsonMap() {
    }

    String serialize() {
        return JSON.encode(map);
    }

    JsonMap.unserialize(String serializedString) {
        this.map = JSON.decode(serializedString);
    }
}
```

You can (de)serialize like so:

```
JsonMap m = new JsonMap();
m.map = { 'test': 1 };
print(m.serialize());

JsonMap n = new JsonMap.unserialize('{"hello": 1}');
print(n.map);
```

While testing this, I noticed that Dart will not throw any errors at you if you dont actually implement the methods that your class promises to implement with `implements`. This might just be a hicc-up with my local Dart, though.

Comment: Your last paragraph is the exact situation that he is trying to avoid.

Comment: I get that, but abstract classes are the Dart way to do this. The core Dart classes use this for interfaces like Comparable or Iterable. I dont know why Dart does not enforce a warning or an error if the implementation is incomplete.

Comment: Comparable or Iterable are different though, as implementations don't have to define a constructor to work properly. Constructors are not part of a class's interface, so the editor doesn't show any warning.